# Zapier webhook url alternative

Tags: javascript, html, webhooks, zapier

We are using zapier's webhooks to collect answers we gather via html5 formatted mail messages. The mail is created with zapier and includes some dynamic info and two buttons to make your choice. These button actions are each linked to a different webhook. The webhook provided by zapier has a static part and a dynamic part which is a zapier variable. When the receiver pushes the button, a blank browser window shows up with, whether a short text or in "silent mode" a blank page.
Although we are sending an extra mail as confirmation for the decision made via mail, we would like to either avoid the showing of this blank page at all or maybe replace it by a customized HTML page that shows a more attractive web page. 
We tried different approaches like using an additional javascript onlick action on the button to achieve the opening of two pages with one click. One with the webhook blank page as the trigger and another one with a nice confirmation message page for a nice user experience. Unfortunately, there are some mail client limitations that seems not to allow javascript executions. 
Is there any workaround like using any third-party service that offers webhook containers with the possibility to customize the content of the page linked to the webhook URL or any idea on how to link a button action to two url’s?
Thank you for reading this long question. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

I can't speak to other options, but the best choice for you here is probably to have the email link go to a static page with two buttons. That way, you'll be in the browser and can do whatever you need with JS. This is likely buttons that have `onClick` handlers and then show nice confirmations.

It also avoids false clicks, where a mail client tries to load external resources (which normally doesn't matter, but in this case can trigger a webhook).

Comment: Hi David. Thank you for your answer. I agree, the static page option solves the javascript limitation, but I don’t know how to make Zapier take control of the dynamic link creation using this method. In our HTML mail body approach, zapier creates the mail body content and the web hooks attached to each button that has a static part and a variable part that zapier adds using a variale in reference to every action. How do I get zapier to do this on the static web page approach?
Thank you in advance for your help.